# Creating Increment Calculations in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

What I may have learned is that AutoNumber data types in Access are Read Only and cannot be edited. 
I am having trouble with the the following SQL Code:
SELECT BaseClassID, BaseClassID+1 as BaseClassIncrement
FROM BaseClasses;

This returned the values in a query:
BaseClassID | BaseClassIncrement
      1     |          2

Will it work when in form view after I apply this in command button wizard?
It would be after I selected RunQuery after I close the BaseClasses form.
Afterwards, it will it increments in the form after user reopens it.

How could I improve this task?

JohnDB

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the command suggest, `SELECT` does not modify the records it selects. In this case you are merely returning a row that contains an increment on that row alone. It does not increment anything.